# R - How to extract unique dates from a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I extract unique dates from a data frame?

For instance:

```
structure(list(particles = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), timestamp = c(1469945933290, 
    1469945937786, 1469945940819, 1469945944000, 1469945948113, 1469945951115
    ), date = structure(c(1469945933.29, 1469945937.786, 1469945940.819, 
    1469945944, 1469945948.113, 1469945951.115), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC-1")), .Names = c("particles", "timestamp", 
    "date"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, the unique dates for this data frame is only `2016-07-31`. But I have more data from different dates coming in, they could be:

```
2016-08-01
2016-08-08
2016-08-31
etc
```

So I want to get all the unique ones in this data frame. They should be:

```
2016-07-31
2016-08-01
2016-08-08
2016-08-31
etc
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `unique(as.Date(df$date))`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks.